# Issue in flutter web text over lapping with the behind text

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have created a flutter web app in that i am using popup menu. When i try to click the menu then it is not visible clearly due to the overlapping issue with the behind Text.

i have tried multiple ways by changing background colour of menu but not fixed.

Please help me on this issue.